# How to center a div after zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I'm having a little trouble with what I thought would be quite easy. I'm trying to implement a map where you can zoom in and out with your mousewheel. This part works perfectly fine, but it's alway zooming that the top left corner stays at (0/0). I tried to give it the typical google maps zoom, but it didnt really work out.

I prepared a little [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UGCA/) for you to see what I'm talking about. As I said I tried to implement the centering part already in the `centerOnMouse` function, but I had no luck so far. maybee anyone can suggest how it can be altered to fit my needs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to align your map around the center of your viewport, take the half width and the half height of the viewport and make your zooming calculations from that point. You can also use the mouse's point in the viewport to zoom towards it.

Comment: Wow, I could hit myself right now: The formula was working, but this was my code were I actually set the scroll:
scrollableEl.scrollLeft(scrollX);
scrollableEl.scrollTop(scrollX);
No wonder it didnt work... thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Its allways the little stuff ^^